# TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'vService.CheckService' threw an exception

Tags: c#, wcf, faultexception

I am receiving a FaultException from a WCF service as follows when it is invoked:

```
2012-04-02 16:26:00.3593|Error|System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: The type initializer for 'vService.CheckService' threw an exception. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'vService.CheckService' threw an exception. ----> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at vService.CheckService..cctor() in d:\working\code\VioletServer\vService\CheckService.cs:line 14
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at vService.CheckService..ctor()
   at CreatevService.CheckService()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceProvider.GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message request)
   at System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
  ...).
```

Line 14 of CheckService.cs is

```
private static string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["violetdb"].ConnectionString;
```

What does the exception mean in this context and how can I resolve it?

---

```
//CheckService.cs
public class CheckService : ICheckService
{
    private static string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["violetdb"].ConnectionString;
    MessageRepository _repo = new MessageRepository(connStr);

    public CheckService(){}

    public CheckService(MessageRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string sender, string recipient, string messagetext)
    {
        _repo.DeliverMessage(sender,recipient,messagetext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your WCF service does not have a connection string named "violetdb" in its application configuration file.

A `TypeInitializerException` is thrown in this circumstance, because you have a `static` field which is being initialised ahead of type construction, and because the `ConnectionStrings["violetdb"]` call is returning `null`, and it is throwing an `NullReferenceException`.

Bottom line, check the `<connectionStrings>` section of your configuration file and ensure that the connection string exists.

Comment: I had the `violetdb` connection string in `<connectionString>` section in the `web.config` file. Since the project is a class library, I just added an `app.config` file and copied the connection string over. I still get the exception.

Comment: Where are you hosting your application? Is it self hosted (i.e. a console app, or windows service? Is it hosted in IIS?

Comment: It is self hosted in a console application.

Comment: Is it possible to debug what is happening with the service?

Comment: Matthew, I set the connection string manually and found that it worked. I find it odd that the connection string did not get picked up from app.config. I have never seen this happen. Do you have insight into this?

Comment: Sure, I would start by simply running your console application and see if the exception is thrown when you call the service. If not, click `Debug` > `Exceptions` and check the `Thrown` checkbox for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

Comment: Okay, I will check that. Appreciate your help.